# Убивать процесс жрущий много памяти

Tags: ubuntu

Есть ли софт какой-то, который будет мониторить приложения, которые стремительно начинают потреблять много ОЗУ и убивать их? 
Сталкиваюсь с тем, что при прослушивании музыки в вк, либо при открытии сайтов ОС зависает намертво (браузер Опера), если во-время не выключить вкладку, но заметить такое крайне не просто. Мемтестом оперативку не прогонял пока, т.к. если и буду покупать новые планки, то через пару недель. А проблема эта доставляет массу неудобств

Кстати, параметр vm.swappiness равен нулю. Сейчас поставил 10, может проблема пропадет

Comment: google://настройка oom killer linux, правда, память тут не при чем, у вас или драйвер какой-нибудь или браузер (или связка браузер+убунта) глючит.

Comment: Такая проблема была и на windows, но ОС не зависала, позволяя мне убить процесс. Браузер менять бы не хотелось, сейчас погуглю oom killer, спасибо!

Comment: @jessez, напишите :) Для затравки: `ps -auxf | sort -nr -k 3 | head -10` вот 10 процессов, которые жрут больше всего памяти в данный момент. Задайте максимальное значение, при превышении его - убивать. Скрипт пишется на коленке  быстрей, чем комментарий :) Другой вопрос насколько это оправдано окажется...

Comment: @PinkTux опера ведь на движке хрома написана, и под каждую отдельную вкладку создает свой процесс. Это не помешает написать скрипт? Понятия не имею, как его написать, но погуглю, если имеет смысл :))

Comment: Ну, это уже творчески :) Сейчас попробую что-нибудь накорябать для примера.

Comment: @PinkTux буду очень благодарен :)

Comment: Система виснет намертво если что-то отжирает вовсе не память, а время.процессора.

Comment: OOM killer не пойдёт?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот, например, тупейший подход. Не будем вдаваться в подробности: насколько это корректно, не обрушим ли мы систему, и пр.

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ 1 ] 
do
  # получаем %памяти, имя процесса, его PID и юзера:
  ps axo %mem,comm,pid,euser | \
  # если процесс занимает больше 10% - убиваем:
  awk -F' ' '{ \
    if( $1 > 10 ) { \ 
      printf( "KILL %s:%s - %s\n",$2,$4,$3 ); \
      system( "kill -9 " $3 ); \
    } \
  }'

  sleep 10

done
```

Можно пойти дальше: сначала определять сколько памяти свободно, и запускать убийства только если осталось меньше какого-то предела. Ввести список неубиваемых исключений, высчитывать не %% вообще, а от занятой/свободной памяти, и т.д. Например:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;

# свободной памяти больше - не дёргаемся:
use constant MIN_FREE_MEM => 40;
# сколько %% памяти разрешается занимать процессу:
use constant MAX_PROCESS_MEM => 10;
use constant SLEEP_DELAY     => 10;

# будем использовать смотреть точное совпадение,
# но можно и под регекспы переделать
my %excludes = (
    'init'    => 1,
    'eclipse' => 1,
);

while (1) {
  # элементы массива будут такими:
  #   0        1             2        3
  # [ %памяти, имя процесса, его PID, юзер ]
  my @pinfo = map {
    s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    [ split /\s+/ ];
  } split "\n", `ps axo %mem,comm,pid,euser`;

  # удалить первую строку с заголовком
  shift @pinfo;

  my $free = 100.0;
  $free -= $_->[0] for @pinfo;
  # теперь мы знаем сколько %% памяти свободно

  if ( $free < MIN_FREE_MEM ) {
    # пропускаем исключения:
    next if $excludes{ $_->[1] };
    for (@pinfo) {
      if ( $_->[0] > MAX_PROCESS_MEM ) {
        say "Killing process $_->[2]:$_->[1]:$_->[3] ($_->[0]%)";
        kill '-KILL', $_->[2];
      }
    }
  }
  sleep SLEEP_DELAY;
}
```

Comment: Вот это отдача :)) Спасибо! А как список с не убиваемыми исключениями сделать? Intellij idea жрет много памяти, а ее убивать бы не хотелось ))

Comment: Добавил исключения. Но не знаю как выглядит idea, подозреваю, что там будут висеть процессы с простым именем 'java'... (*проверил, точно, два процесса `java`, как их отличать фиг знает, только если все java в исключения*). Если нужно смотреть не память, а загрузку процессора, то можно смотреть не вывод `ps`, а `top -b -n 1`, например. Впрочем, top и для памяти юзать можно.

Comment: спасибо! Все java в исключения добавлю :) Процессор не грузит совсем, когда такая проблема имеет место. Еще раз благодарю!

Comment: упс, кидает ошибку
Scalar found where operator expected at ./defenderOOM.sh line 40, near "'-KILL' $_"
 (Missing operator before  $_?)
syntax error at ./defenderOOM.sh line 40, near "'-KILL' $_"

Comment: Запятая: `kill '-KILL' $_->[2]` => `kill '-KILL', $_->[2]`

Comment: еще иногда в консоли выводит Use of uninitialized value in hash element at ./defender.sh line 36 В строчке: next if $excludes{ $_->[1] };

Comment: э... `next if defined $excludes{$_->[1]};`

Comment: А почему так получается? Массив ведь задан. Ругается все равно :(

Comment: А может туда имя процесса пустое приходит. Тогда перед этой строкой добавить `next unless $_[1];` (можно в одно условие обе проверки завернуть, но и так нормально)

Comment: Больше не ругается, спасибо :)